# How to set envelope id in MailMessage class in C#?

Tags: c#, smtp

I want to implement automated email delivery tracking and I found out I could do this using the Delivery Status Notification and setting envelope id to track which email has been delivered/not delivered.

However I can't seem to find a way to set the envelope id parameter using the MailMessage class in C#. As I understand this parameter should go in the MAIL FROM header, something like:

MAIL FROM: RET=HDRS ENVID=QQ314159

I tried setting it using message.Headers.Add(), however when I receive the email and inspect its headers I don't see the envelope id in the 'From' header, as it gets it value from the message.From class property and I can't insert anything else than the email address there.

Can't find any information, anybody has some experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually do this with System.Net.Mail, but you can do it using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit):

http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Smtp_SmtpClient_GetEnvelopeId.htm